IN EXCEL split connections based on in between points in X,Y locations
I start from an inputlist of points with X,Y locations and an input list of beginning and end points from the first list.
How to get an output list with sub (inbetween) connections if a point is situated between the starting and end location (either in X or Y direction).
In the figure below A4:C14 input locations/labeled arbitrairy.
E4:F10 input connections from user.
J4:K16 Desired output format with 'splitted' connections in between.
I have tried with MAKEARRAY and also with LET/VSTACK, but I didn't succeed.


Just for fun, until an eventual Excel 365 solution shows up, here a formula based solution for Excel 2016:










Start
P3
P1
P2
P10
P3
P11
P12











End
P1
P9
P10
P12
P13
P9
P13


ID
X
Y














P1
0
14,615




Table
A4:C14








P2
0
7,605




Range ID
A4:A14








P3
0
0




Range X
B4:B14








P4
4
7,605




Range Y
C4:C14








P5
10
4














P9
10
14,615




Column ID
=CELL("address",INDIRECT("C"&CELL("col",INDIRECT(I5)),FALSE))&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT("R1C"&CELL("col",INDIRECT(I5)),FALSE),ROWS(I:I)-1,0))








P10
10
7,605














P11
10
0




Start X
=VLOOKUP(I1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(J1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(K1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(L1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(M1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(N1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(O1,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)


P12
15
7,605




End X
=VLOOKUP(I2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(J2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(K2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(L2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(M2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(N2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(O2,INDIRECT($I$4),2,FALSE)


P6
10
12




Start Y
=VLOOKUP(I1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(J1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(K1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(L1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(M1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(N1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(O1,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)


P13
15
0




End Y
=VLOOKUP(I2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(J2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(K2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(L2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(M2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(N2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(O2,INDIRECT($I$4),3,FALSE)









Alignment 1=X 2=Y
=CHOOSE((I11=I12)*2^0+(I13=I14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)
=CHOOSE((J11=J12)*2^0+(J13=J14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)
=CHOOSE((K11=K12)*2^0+(K13=K14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)
=CHOOSE((L11=L12)*2^0+(L13=L14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)
=CHOOSE((M11=M12)*2^0+(M13=M14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)
=CHOOSE((N11=N12)*2^0+(N13=N14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)
=CHOOSE((O11=O12)*2^0+(O13=O14)*2^1+1,#N/A,1,2,1)









Start
=OFFSET(I14,-(I15-1)*2-1,0)
=OFFSET(J14,-(J15-1)*2-1,0)
=OFFSET(K14,-(K15-1)*2-1,0)
=OFFSET(L14,-(L15-1)*2-1,0)
=OFFSET(M14,-(M15-1)*2-1,0)
=OFFSET(N14,-(N15-1)*2-1,0)
=OFFSET(O14,-(O15-1)*2-1,0)









End
=OFFSET(I14,-(I15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(J14,-(J15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(K14,-(K15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(L14,-(L15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(M14,-(M15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(N14,-(N15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(O14,-(O15-1)*2,0)









Costant
=OFFSET(I11,(I15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(J11,(J15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(K11,(K15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(L11,(L15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(M11,(M15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(N11,(N15-1)*2,0)
=OFFSET(O11,(O15-1)*2,0)









Going up/right?
=I16<I17
=J16<J17
=K16<K17
=L16<L17
=M16<M17
=N16<N17
=O16<O17









Range 1
=CHOOSE(I$15,$I$7,$I$6)
=CHOOSE(J$15,$I$7,$I$6)
=CHOOSE(K$15,$I$7,$I$6)
=CHOOSE(L$15,$I$7,$I$6)
=CHOOSE(M$15,$I$7,$I$6)
=CHOOSE(N$15,$I$7,$I$6)
=CHOOSE(O$15,$I$7,$I$6)









Range 2
=CHOOSE(I$15,$I$6,$I$7)
=CHOOSE(J$15,$I$6,$I$7)
=CHOOSE(K$15,$I$6,$I$7)
=CHOOSE(L$15,$I$6,$I$7)
=CHOOSE(M$15,$I$6,$I$7)
=CHOOSE(N$15,$I$6,$I$7)
=CHOOSE(O$15,$I$6,$I$7)


























Variable coordinate 1
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I23)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J23)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K23)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L23)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M23)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N23)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O23)),"")









Variable coordinate 2
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I24)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J24)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K24)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L24)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M24)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N24)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O24)),"")









Variable coordinate 3
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I25)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J25)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K25)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L25)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M25)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N25)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O25)),"")









Variable coordinate 4
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I26)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J26)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K26)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L26)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M26)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N26)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O26)),"")









Variable coordinate 5
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I27)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J27)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K27)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L27)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M27)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N27)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O27)),"")









Variable coordinate 6
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I28)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J28)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K28)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L28)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M28)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N28)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O28)),"")









Variable coordinate 7
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I29)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J29)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K29)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L29)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M29)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N29)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O29)),"")









Variable coordinate 8
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I30)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J30)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K30)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L30)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M30)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N30)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O30)),"")









Variable coordinate 9
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I31)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J31)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K31)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L31)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M31)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N31)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O31)),"")









Variable coordinate 10
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I32)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J32)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K32)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L32)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M32)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N32)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O32)),"")









Variable coordinate 11
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(I$20)/(INDIRECT(I$20)>=MIN(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$20)<=MAX(I$16:I$17))/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),ROWS($I$23:I33)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(J$20)/(INDIRECT(J$20)>=MIN(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$20)<=MAX(J$16:J$17))/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),ROWS($I$23:J33)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(K$20)/(INDIRECT(K$20)>=MIN(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$20)<=MAX(K$16:K$17))/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),ROWS($I$23:K33)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(L$20)/(INDIRECT(L$20)>=MIN(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$20)<=MAX(L$16:L$17))/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),ROWS($I$23:L33)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(M$20)/(INDIRECT(M$20)>=MIN(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$20)<=MAX(M$16:M$17))/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),ROWS($I$23:M33)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(N$20)/(INDIRECT(N$20)>=MIN(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$20)<=MAX(N$16:N$17))/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),ROWS($I$23:N33)),"")
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(IF($I$19,15,14),6,INDIRECT(O$20)/(INDIRECT(O$20)>=MIN(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$20)<=MAX(O$16:O$17))/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),ROWS($I$23:O33)),"")


























Point 1
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I23)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J23)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K23)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L23)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M23)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N23)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O23)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 2
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I24)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J24)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K24)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L24)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M24)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N24)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O24)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 3
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I25)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J25)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K25)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L25)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M25)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N25)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O25)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 4
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I26)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J26)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K26)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L26)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M26)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N26)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O26)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 5
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I27)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J27)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K27)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L27)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M27)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N27)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O27)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 6
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I28)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J28)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K28)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L28)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M28)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N28)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O28)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 7
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I29)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J29)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K29)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L29)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M29)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N29)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O29)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 8
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I30)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J30)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K30)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L30)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M30)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N30)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O30)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 9
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I31)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J31)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K31)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L31)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M31)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N31)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O31)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 10
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I32)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J32)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K32)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L32)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M32)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N32)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O32)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")









Point 11
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(I$20)=I33)/(INDIRECT(I$21)=I$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(J$20)=J33)/(INDIRECT(J$21)=J$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(K$20)=K33)/(INDIRECT(K$21)=K$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(L$20)=L33)/(INDIRECT(L$21)=L$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(M$20)=M33)/(INDIRECT(M$21)=M$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(N$20)=N33)/(INDIRECT(N$21)=N$18),1)),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT($I$9),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(INDIRECT($I$5))/(INDIRECT(O$20)=O33)/(INDIRECT(O$21)=O$18),1)),"")



Here a screenshot:


Thanks for the effort, but I really need the 'OUTPUT' desired result table layout on the rigth my real tables are much larger so the 2016 solution is not working for me.

Ye, i was kind of expecting that. Is a VBA solution acceptable? Since i don't have the latest functions i can't really create a viable formula based solution.

should be possible with one of the functions I mentioned. VBA rather not, it has to be transparant to my clients.
